# Rails params nil when they appear to be there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, link-to

In Rails, I am trying to learn how to use params passed with link_to.

In one view I have

```
<%= link_to 'link', static_pages_params_path(info: 23) %>
```

Then in my StaticPagesController I have

```
def params
  debugger
end
```

When I enter byebug after clicking the aforementioned link, I see

```
Started GET "/static_pages/params?info=23" for ::1 at 2016-08-17 11:05:43 -0500
Processing by StaticPagesController#params as HTML
  Parameters: {"info"=>"23"}
Return value is: nil
```

From this it appears that I should be able to access params. However, when I enter params into byebug, I get nil:

```
(byebug) params
nil
```

I am debugging at this point because I was unable to access params[:info] from the params method.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you will get a name-space collision here and an infinite loop, since it can't differentiate between the method and the params variable. You should definitely rename your action and retry.

Comment: That's exactly what the problem was. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting a name-space collision with the controller method overriding your `params` variable. Consider changing your action name.